# What are the properties and codomain of the spin $\alpha$, $\beta$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin

I am following Mike Finnis's book *Interatomic forces in condensed matter*. I believe he uses the letter $s_i$ to denote spin number $\pm 1/2$ for fermions for example. But he has two functions $\alpha,\beta$ that he calls the spin, (I thought $\pm 1/2$ was the spin). What is their codomain and their mathematical properties? And why do we need these functions, and not just the spin numbers themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deal with spin in full abstraction, you have a spin state $|\psi_\mathrm{spin}\rangle$ which lives in the spin Hilbert space $\mathcal S \cong \mathbb C^2$, and you can take the spin components of this spin vector by taking its inner product against any arbitrary unit vector on $\mathcal S$, say, $|\varphi\rangle$ to give you a complex number $\langle\phi|\psi_\mathrm{spin}\rangle= \psi_\mathrm{spin} \in\mathbb C$.

In quantum chemistry (and, apparently, also in some sectors of condensed matter), this abstract approach is sometimes unpalatable, and people like to work with explicit components.

(This is analogous to, and partly due to, how they ditch the abstract state-vector language of $|\psi_\mathrm{space}\rangle \in \mathcal H = L_2(\mathbb R^3)$ for explicit wavefunctions $\psi_\mathrm{space}(\mathbf r) = \langle\mathbf r| \psi_\mathrm{space} \rangle$.)

This is where the "$\alpha$" and "$\beta$" notation comes in:

- They fix an orthonormal basis $A=\{|\alpha\rangle,|\beta\rangle\}$ for $\mathcal S$, which is completely arbitrary.

  (Because of the structure of this Hilbert space, they must correspond to the "up" and "down" spin states along *some* quantization axis, but this is completely irrelevant to the theory, unless the spin is going to interface with spatially-directional objects such as an external magnetic field.)
- They fix some quantization axis $\hat n$ on which to take components, in the same way that they fix the position representation as a basis in which to examine $|\psi_\mathrm{space}\rangle$.
- In other words, they choose a basis $B=\left\{\left|{+\tfrac12},\hat n\right\rangle, \left|{-\tfrac12},\hat n\right\rangle \right\}$ in which to take the spin components. $|s\rangle$ denotes an arbitrary state from $B$ (in the same way that $|\mathbf r\rangle$ denotes an arbitrary state from the spatial position basis $\{|\mathbf r\rangle\}$).
- The spin components are notated by
  $$
  \alpha(s) = \langle s|\alpha\rangle
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  \beta(s) = \langle s|\beta\rangle,
  $$
  respectively, for each of the two basis states of $A$.
- As such, the spin components $\alpha(s),\beta(s)\in \mathbb C$ are complex numbers.
- However, they're not arbitrary complex numbers ─ they are subject to the requirement that the base-change matrix
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha(1/2) & \beta(1/2) \\ \alpha(-1/2) & \beta(-1/2) 
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \left\langle\tfrac12\middle|\alpha\right\rangle & 
  \left\langle\tfrac12\middle|\beta\right\rangle \\ 
  \left\langle-\tfrac12\middle|\alpha\right\rangle & 
  \left\langle-\tfrac12\middle|\beta\right\rangle
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  be unitary.
- In practice, unless you've got specific requirements, you're likely to choose $A=B$, i.e. identical quantization axes for your basis states and the components you observe it in, in which case $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ are alternating $1$s and $0$s, but working at that level of specificity actually *harms* your ability to develop a clean and understandable formalism, and it's better to work in this slightly more abstract notation.

That's about it, really.